# Using logical operators with macros

Tags: c, macros, conditional-compilation

I have a piece of code which I want to include if either of two macros are defined

```
#ifdef MACRO1 || MACRO2

void foo()
{


}

#endif
```

How do I accomplish this in C?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Besides `#ifdef`, the preprocessor supports the more general `#if` instruction; actually, `#ifdef MACRO` is a shortcut for `#if defined(MACRO)`, where `defined` is a "preprocessor function" that returns 1 if the macro is defined; so, you can do:

```
#if defined(MACRO1) || defined(MACRO2)

void foo()
{


}

#endif
```

Comment: What is the issue in below code? What is the alternative in case such kind of usage is incorrect?
#define CUSTOM_METHOD 1
#define ARDUINO_METHOD 2
#define TIMER_DELAY_METHOD CUSTOM_METHOD
#if defined (TIMER_DELAY_METHOD != CUSTOM_METHOD) || defined(TIMER_DELAY_METHOD!=ARDUINO_METHOD)
#error "No timer method is defined"
#endif // defined

Comment: I think I got it and following code seems to be working
#define CUSTOM_METHOD 1
#define ARDUINO_METHOD 2
#define NONE 3
#define TIMER_DELAY_METHOD NONE
#if (TIMER_DELAY_METHOD != CUSTOM_METHOD) && (TIMER_DELAY_METHOD != ARDUINO_METHOD)
#error "No timer method is defined"
#endif // defined

Answer (score 5):

```
#if defined(MACRO1) || defined(MACRO2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here the NOT version if needed:

```
#if !defined(MACRO1) && !defined(MACRO2)
...
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  #if defined(Macro 1) + defined(Macro 2) == 1
  <Code>
  #endif
```